# Has there been a body text CSS change on EE.SE?

Tags: bug

[image]

The line spacing on Q&A text has opened up making each line look like a separate paragraph. This is the same on Chrome / IE and on Android Chrome.

Are some of the guys in the basement twiddling with the knobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, line spacing has been increased as mentioned here on Meta Stack Exchange: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/295232)

Many people don't like the change, and posts like [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/295232) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353529/295232) are very popular right now.